# How to trigger an AWS Lambda function only when a new object is added to a nested array in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating a filter criteria for an AWS function triggered by a DynamoDB event, however I only want this function to be triggered when a determined field in the object changes. Here is a simplified version of the objects I'm storing on DynamoDB:

```
{
 "databases": [
  {
   "file_name": "db.ods",
   "upload_date": "2023-05-30T12:39:22.000Z",
   "url": "https://an-s3-path/db.ods"
  }
 ],
 "updated_at": "2023-05-30T12:38:54.000Z",
 "created_at": "2023-05-30T12:38:54.000Z"
}
```

Now I want to trigger the function only when the user adds a new database, which is equivalent to just modify the array under the `databases` key adding a new object. How could I achieve it? So far this is the filter I'm using, but it only checks if the field `url` exists:

```
{
  "dynamodb": {
    "databases": {
      "url": [{"exists": true}]
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, I added the next filter to only trigger the function if the user updates/creates a record, since I don't want to do anything when it's removed:

```
{
  "eventName": [
    "INSERT",
    "MODIFY"
  ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to detect if the user added a new object under the `databases` array so I guess I need to compare old and new values somehow, but I haven't found any information about how to do it.

I've read the official documentation on AWS but didn't find anything useful, all the available information is about comparing values using operators like "eq", "contains", "exists", etc., but nothing about detecting changes in nested objects.